# Sum all values from a php array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a easy way to count all the elements values from an array ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 1
    [17] => 1
    [18] => 
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 
    [21] => 
    [22] => 
    [23] => 
    [24] => 1
)
```

For the above array i should get the value = 7
Thanks

Comment: `array_sum(array_filter($array))`. array_filter will remove empty indexes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) will do the job for you.

This function returns sum of all array elements integer or float.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_sum()` like this:

```
echo array_sum($array);
```

If you want for some reason to remove "blanks", user this:

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in function array_sum() for more details follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: not efficient code. you have built-in function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution

```
$sum = array_sum(array_filter($array));
```